# How to combine json object by "foreign key" relationship

Tags: javascript, json

I have two objects returned from two different rest resources.

```
{
"id": 1,
"username": "jdoe"
}

{
"role_id": 1,
"role": "developer",
"members": [
    1,
    3,
    5
]
}
```

I'd like to use plain ole javascript to combine these two objects based into one where id is in the members array, so that i get back an object like has roles as the top node, then lists users of that role underneath.

Easily done?

Comment: So this question about manipulation JavaScript objects, not JSON? It would be helpful if you could provide an example of the result. There is no such thing as a "JSON object": http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/.

Comment: To each their own.  As the article you linked to states, Crockford use the term JSON Object. But that's a good point, +1 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem a couple weeks ago with a set of 10 AJAX calls that I wanted to mesh together.  A simple method is to create a lookup table from the `id` values, then use the lookup table to combine the results.  Here's an example using multiple users and multiple roles:

```
var users = [
    { "id": 1, "username": "jdoe" },
    { "id": 3, "username": "dbob" },
    { "id": 5, "username": "jske" }
];
var roles = [
    { "role_id": 1, "role": "developer", "members": [1,3,5] },
    { "role_id": 2, "role": "admin", "members": [5] }
];

// create lookup table
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
    users.lookup[users[i].id] = users[i];

// populate members from users with lookup table
for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < roles[i].members.length; j++)
        roles[i].members[j] = users.lookup[roles[i].members[j]];
```

Now the members in roles are references to the users rather than just the id's:

```
[
  { "role_id": 1, "role": "developer", "members":
    [{ "id": 1, "username": "jdoe" },
     { "id": 3, "username": "dbob" },
     { "id": 5, "username": "jske" }] },
  { "role_id": 2, "role": "admin", "members": 
    [{ "id": 5, "username": "jske" }] }
]
```

And you can reference the usernames in a role like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < roles[0].members.length; i++)
    alert(roles[0].members[i].username);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2aqR5/1/