# Angularjs map array to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have two arrays, **Users** and **Employments** like so:

```
Users       = [{id:1, name: "ryan"}, {id:2, name:"Julie"}]
Employments = [{user_id: 1, title: "manager"}, {user_id: 2, title: "Professor"}]
```

I'd like to display the Employments array in an ng-repeat like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="employment in Employments">
  {{employment.user.name}}
</li>
```

How do I map the Users array to the Employments array?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647694/how-to-combine-json-object-by-foreign-key-relationship

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the employee name to get displayed based on id, the simplest way is just pass that id to a function and return the name, like as shown below

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fskqtf9p/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <li ng-repeat="employment in Employments">{{getEmployeeName(employment.user_id)}}
    </li>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Users = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "ryan"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Julie"
    }];

    $scope.Employments = [{
        user_id: 1,
        title: "manager"
    }, {
        user_id: 2,
        title: "Professor"
    }];

    $scope.getEmployeeName = function (empId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Users.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.Users[i].id === empId) {
                return $scope.Users[i].name;
            }
        };
    };
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you want to embed the User array in the Employments array, try the following stuff

```
$scope.Users = [{id: 1, name: "ryan"}, {id: 2, name: "Julie"}];

$scope.Employments = [{user_id: 1, title: "manager"}, 
                      {user_id: 2, title: "Professor"}
                     ];
```

code for flattening Employments array by adding User properties

```
angular.forEach($scope.Users, function (user, userIndex) {
    angular.forEach($scope.Employments, function (employee, employeeIndex) {
        if (employee.user_id === user.id) {
            employee.name = user.name;
        }
    });
});
```

**Output**

```
$scope.Employments = [ { user_id: 1, title: "manager", name: "ryan" }, 
                       { user_id: 2, title: "Professor", name: "Julie" } 
                     ]
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9bbmefn8/)**

**UPDATE 3**

Code for making a nested employee structure like as shown below from `$scope.Users` and `$scope.Employments`

```
$scope.employees = [];
angular.forEach($scope.Employments, function (employee, employeeIndex) {
    var employeeObject = {};
    employeeObject.title = employee.title;
    angular.forEach($scope.Users, function (user, userIndex) {
        if (employee.user_id === user.id) {
            employeeObject.user = user;
        }
    });
    $scope.employees.push(employeeObject);
});
```

**Output**

```
[ { title: "manager", user: { "id": 1, "name": "ryan" } }, 
  { title: "Professor", user: { "id": 2, "name": "Julie" } } 
]
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1ovpaabt/)**

Comment: This works great. Thanks Nidhish. Is there a way to embed the User array in the Employments array? I actually have about half a dozen arrays and writing a function for every association would rapidly bloat the code base. Or would you advise that I write a function for every association to keep things separate?

Comment: @Ryan.lay is that you want

Comment: something more like this:  Employments = [{ title: "manager", { user: { id: 1, name: ryan}}}, { title: "Professor", {user: { id: 2, name: "Julie"}}}].

Comment: By embedding the arrays as such, I'm hoping to enable the referencing of other user.attributes like {{employment.user.address}} etc. without having to explicitly map every single property to the Employments array.

Comment: Sorry if the questions seem simplistic, javascript is a new thing for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to match up the two following arrays purely with a template you could take the following arrays

```
Users       = [{id:1, name: "ryan"}, {id:2, name:"Julie"}]
Employments = [{user_id: 1, title: "manager"}, {user_id: 2, title: "Professor"}]
```

And nest a repeat like:

```
    <li ng-repeat="employment in Employments">
      <div ng-repeat="user in Users" ng-if="user.id === employment.user_id" >
        {{user.name}}:{{employment.title}}
      </div>
    </li>
```

Two more nice little thing to do to avoid any risk of getting those brackets showing on a slow page load is to use the ng-bind and prefix the attributes with data so its with the html spec

```
        <li data-ng-repeat="employment in Employments">
          <div data-ng-repeat="user in Users" data-ng-if="user.id === employment.user_id" >
            <span data-ng-bind="user.name"></span>:<span data-ng-bind="employment.title"></span>
          </div>
        </li>
```

I know you didn't have the need for anything but the name, but figured a quick example of using the outer loop in the inner still could be helpful. Also this would be the case for ng-init if you needed to reference the the $index of the outer ng-repeat from the inner, but that might be more than you're looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview)

This sorts the users names into the employments array:

```
var sortUsers = function() {
  var i = 0;
  for (i; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
    console.log($scope.users[i].id)
    for(var z = 0; z < $scope.employments.length; z++) {
      if($scope.employments[z].user_id === $scope.users[i].id) {
        $scope.employments[z].name = $scope.users[i].name;    
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="employment in employments">
  {{employment.name}}
      </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dealt similar problem yesterday. If you want to use js, have to loop twice. 
I recommend to use the best way is to select in one query by join table if data come from single database.

You select User by one query, and Employment for another query in database. Then, twice ng-repeat to re-arrange. Here is my solution.

```
select users.*, employments.title from `users` inner join `employments` where users.id = employments.user_id;
```

Hope be be helpful.