# Angular - can I keep two arrays separated and use them in an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

first of all, this is an extension of this question here: [Angularjs map array to another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044067/angularjs-map-array-to-another-array#answer-30044169)

Currently, I have two scopes:

```
$scope.products = [
  {id: 001, name: "prod 1", ...},
  {id: 002, name: "prod 2", ...},
  {id: 003, name: "prod 3", ...},
  {id: 004, name: "prod 4", ...},
  {id: 005, name: "prod 5", ...}
]

$scope.cart = {
  products: [001,002]
  ...
}
```

`$scope.products` contains a list of all the available products with the products information, while `$scope.cart.products` contain a list of IDs added to the cart.

The answer above explains how to merge the two arrays together, however, I'd like to keep them separate and create a sort of map between the two. Is it possible? Is a custom filter in the repeater the best option here, or there's a built-in way to do this in angular? thanks for any suggestion

**EDIT**

Filter:

```
filter('mapProducts', function($filter) {
  return function(products, ids) {
    var result;
    result = [];
    $filter('filter')(products, function(p) {
      if (ids.indexOf(p.id) !== -1) {
        return result.push(p);
      }
    });
    return result;
  };
});
```

and in the repeater:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | mapProducts:cart.products">
```

Comment: How do you want to use this map? Is it for the UI?

Comment: Depending on your UI, it seems reasonable to create a custom `isInCard` filter for the product repeater.

Comment: yes, The idea is that if somebody clicks on the cart details, it shows the name, price and other details contained in scope.products, while keeping scope.cart.product as a map without duplicating the same details that are already in scope.products

Comment: Why not just have `$scope.cart` be an array of references to objects in `$scope.products`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get much benefit by not creating a new array. You can use an Angular filter to "map" the results, and that might be cleaner than doing the same thing in the controller, but behind the scenes Angular is actually just creating a new sub-array. Even if you make a custom filter, at the end of the day you are creating a new array.

```
  angular.module('myApp').
  filter('idNumber', function() {
    return function(products,idNumbers) {
      var newArray= [];
      newArray = products.filter(function(p) {
        return idNumbers.find(function(i) {
          return i == p.id;
        });
      })
      return newArray;
    }
  });
```

Additionally, if you use the view version of the filter:

```
ng-repeat="product in products | myFilter: cart.products"
```

There could be a performance hit, depending on how big your array is:

> The filter can be applied in the view template with markup like {{ctrl.array | filter:'a'}}, which would do a fulltext search for "a". However, using a filter in a view template will reevaluate the filter on every digest, which can be costly if the array is big.

That means that you would want to use the filter in the controller:

```
var newArray = $filter($scope.products, 'myFilter', cart.products)
```

Which also means you would be creating a new array.

Answer (score 1):

You can have `$scope.cart.products` be an array of references to objects in `$scope.products`:

```
$scope.products = [
  {id: 001, name: "prod 1", ...},
  {id: 002, name: "prod 2", ...},
  {id: 003, name: "prod 3", ...},
  {id: 004, name: "prod 4", ...},
  {id: 005, name: "prod 5", ...}
];

$scope.cart = {
  products: []
};

$scope.addProduct = function(product) {
  $scope.cart.products.push(product);
}
```

You can see that they are the same object reference:

```
$scope.addProduct($scope.products[1]);

// Returns true
$scope.cart.products[0] === $scope.products[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep it in mind but at the end, I decided to go for a custom filter.

Comment: Do you mind showing what you did? Filters run on each digest cycle, so if you're processing and creating a new array in your filter watch out for performance issues.